# Go to second viewcontroller in NavigationViewController

Tags: ios

I have a `UINavigationController` which points to a `UITableViewController` (a list of items) where there is a segue from a cell to another `UITableViewController` (a screen to edit an item).

On first run of the application, I'd like to skip the first list and immediately go to the second screen, to edit a new item.

The problem is I need to pass the first `UITableViewController`, as I need to be able to go back to that one (or is there a way to set the controller the back button is pointing to?).

Things I've tried and failed:

- Set a boolean `shouldPresentNewItem` on the `UINavigationController` and in the `viewDidLoad` if it is set to `true`, present the first `UITableViewController`, also setting a boolean so I can go to the edit screen.
- Using `self.navigationController!.popToViewController(arr[index] as UIViewController, animated: true)` in the `UINavigationController`s `viewDidLoad`. This gave an error as `self.navigationController` was `nil`. (I don't get why this happens)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In navigation controller set some boolean indicating that you're going to show edit screen and in `viewDidLoad` just push edit view controller without animation:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.presentEditScreen) {
        self.presentEditScreen = NO;
        EditViewController *e = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        [self pushViewController:e animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this worked! Still some trouble with my side menu, but nothing I can't work out I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

simplest way will be. just push from second view to first view

```
   firstViewController *objFirstViewController = [[firstViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:objFirstViewController animated:No];
```

Comment: So you're saying I should embed the edit screen in an `UINavigationController` and in the viewDidLoad push the listview on the stack?

Comment: yes, you have to push to first ViewController... you can't pop back because there is no view in viewController stack. so you can't popToViewController.

Comment: Ooh right, it's a stack. Yes didn't think about that one :) I'll try it out and let you know in a second.

Comment: Can't get it to work, it pushes the listview over the edit screen. I'm currently trying the second answer.